# Default template parameter auto referencing

Tags: c++, templates

I would like to do something like this below. That way I could have a specialization with a field from the same type. Is there a way to have something similar?

```
template<class T = A>
struct A {
    T* t = nullptr;
};

template<class T = B>
struct B : A<T> {
   int x;
};
```

So that this can work:

```
B b1, b2;
b.t = &b2;
b.t->x = 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::conditional_t` to decide the member pointer type based on whether the template parameter is provided:

```
template<class T = struct Default>
struct A { 
   std::conditional_t<std::is_same_v<T, Default>, A*, T*> t;
   int x;
};
```

and similarly, you can inherit from the appropriate type based on whether the template parameter is provided:

```
template<class T = struct Default>
struct B : A<std::conditional_t<std::is_same_v<T, Default>, B<T>, T>> { 
   int y;
};
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/EaPr9Y).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, buit it is still not the same. See here https://godbolt.org/z/f7n9rb

Comment: @ftgo Well, my solution is not using inheritance at all. See the link in the answer for the full solution code. Is there some reason that solution doesn't work for you?

Comment: yes, my intention is to dynamically change the `t` type based on the subclass. When creating a new `A`, I want `t` to be `A`. In the same way, creating a new `B`, I would want `t` to be `B`.

Comment: @ftgo Ok, I think I finally understood what you want. I fixed the solution, and added an example to the demo.

Answer (score 0):

Nailed it using [curiously recurring template pattern (CRTP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) idiom.

Define it like this :

```
template<class T>
struct BaseA {
    T* t = nullptr;
};

struct A : BaseA<A> {
};

template<class T>
struct BaseB : BaseA<T> {
   int x;
};


struct B : BaseB<B> {
   int x;
};
```

So this works as expected :

```
A a1, a2;
a1.t = &a2;
a1.t->x = 10; // compiler error, `A` does not have `x`

B b1, b2;
b1.t = &b2;
b1.t->x = 10; // OK
```

See my [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/aMveGs).